# Brew installation fails on macos

Tags: macos

How could I install brew on macos 10.15.6:

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
```

yields:

```
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
```

Is this a question for StackOverflow or AskDifferent?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable cURL SSL certificate verification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49012543/how-to-disable-curl-ssl-certificate-verification)

Comment: I suppose it does for the subset of users who do not give a damn about security

Answer (score 0):

git clone brewrepowhereveritis

mv brew Library /usr/local