# Installing NPM on WSL2 `curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server`

Tags: ubuntu, npm, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2, nvm

*Background*: I couldn't run any npm commands on my WSL2 Ubuntu 22.042 LTS due to this error:

```
'\\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu-22.04\home\anatoly\rust\ultima\frontend'
CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
```

I've then ran `which npm`, it returned `/mnt/c/Program Files/nodejs//npm` which is, if I uderstand correctly, the mount to my Windows binary.

**Question**: So I tried following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/dev-environment/javascript/nodejs-on-wsl) Microsoft's instruction to install npm specifically for Linux on my Ubuntu.

But when I  `curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/master/install.sh | bash` it returns an error:

```
curl: (60) SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name 'raw.githubusercontent.com'
More details here: https://curl.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49012543/how-to-disable-curl-ssl-certificate-verification) answered my question. Add `-k` to your command but at your own risk.